# Unable to re-define a function in my javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object defined using literal notation as follows (example code used). This is in an external script file.

```
if (RF == null) var RF = {};
RF.Example= {
    onDoSomething: function () { alert('Original Definition');} ,
    method1 : function(){ RF.Example.onDoSomething(); }
}
```

In my .aspx page I have the following ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        RF.Example.onDoSomething = function(){ alert('New Definition'); };
        RF.Example.method1();
    });
```

When the page loads the document.ready is called but the `alert('Original Definition');` is only ever shown. Can someone point me in the right direction. I basically want to redefine the `onDoSomething` function. Thanks, Ben.

**Edit**

Thanks for the comments, I can see that is working. Would it matter that `method1` is actually calling another method that takes the `onDoSomething()` function as a callback parameter?  e.g.

```
method1 : function(){ 
           RF.Example2.callbackFunction(function() {RF.Example.onDoSomething();}); 
          }
```

Comment: Your example is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/TD7E4/ There must be something else going on, that you didn't mention.

Comment: Re Edit: No that shouldn't make a difference. Maybe a reference to `method1` is stored somewhere and that reference is used instead of `method1`? And are you sure the external script file is loaded and executed before `document.ready`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response .. in the end the answer was unrelated to the code posted. Cheers for verifying I wasn't going bonkers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as quoted should work (and does: http://jsbin.com/uguva4), so something other than what's in your question is causing this behavior. For instance, if you're using any kind of JavaScript compiler (like [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler)) or minifier or something, the names may be being changed, which case you're adding a new `onDoSomething` when the old one has been renamed. Alternately, perhaps the alert is being triggered by something else, not what you think is triggering it. Or something else may have grabbed a reference to the old `onDoSomething` (elsewhere in the external script, perhaps) and be using it directly, like this: http://jsbin.com/uguva4/2.